# Validating a phone number with a custom rule possibly using nested groups

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regex for validating phone numbers.

We have custom rules, i.e. the phone number must meet the following pattern:

1. `+` or `00` as a prefix
2. One to three digits
3. An optional space or hyphen
4. Then one to n digits (n is still constrained by the rule for total character count below

The total number of characters must not exceed **28**.

Here is the regex I have come up with:

```
/^((\+|00)(\d{1,3})[\s-]?)(\d{1,23}){1,28}$/
```

I am sure it can be simplified. Can someone please help?

Comment: You could use a positive lookahead to count the number of chars `^(?=.{1,28}$)`

Comment: @Thefourthbird Thanks for your comment. How does this fit in with the other rules? Can you please provide a code sample that integrates the other rules?

Comment: Just put the lookahead before your regex and delete the outermost group and quantifier.

Comment: Taking the rules into account, the pattern could be `^(?=.{1,28}$)(?:\+|00)\d{1,3}[ -]?\d+$` https://regex101.com/r/qoqQ6Y/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird Thanks a lot for your input. It works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part of your pattern `(\d{1,23}){1,28}` matches 1-23 digits followed by repeating that 1-28 times and the maximum is `28×23=644` (Thank you [@Toto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/372239/toto))

You could check if the string consists of 1-28 times the listed characters using a positive lookahead `(?=[+\d -]`

The last part currently is `\d{1,}`, but you could specify a minimum length if you don't want to match `+1 1`

Note that `\s` could also possibly match a newline.

```
^(?=[+\d -]{1,28}$)(?:\+|00)\d{1,3}[ -]?\d{1,}$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ymeTn7/1)

Comment: The maximum is 28×23=644 ;)

Comment: @Toto Thank you, I'm doing 3 things at a time :-)